# SharePoint Foundation 2013 JSLink (CSR) not working

Tags: jslink, client-side-rendering

I have a simple **js** example to try. Here the code:

```
(function () {

    var overrideContext = {};
    overrideContext.Templates = {};
    overrideContext.Templates.Item = overrideTemplate;
    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(overrideContext);

    })();

function overrideTemplate(ctx) {
    return "<div style='font-size:32px;border:solid 1px Silver;'>" + ctx.CurrentItem.Title + "</div>";
}
```

after that I simply add this js to site assets and set into webpart properties. But nothing happens...

[image]

and nothing is changed...
[image]

Am I missing something?

Comment: Did you check whether the JSLink file is loaded? You can use the developer toolbar of your browser to see which script files are loaded.

Comment: nice question. I did it, but i can´t see the js file inside dev tools (IE and Chrome). I try alert("boo"), inside js file too, but not working. I think that js file is not loading... but why?

Comment: Save yourself some head-aches and use Chrome + [the Cisar CSR extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cisar/nifbdojdggkboiifaklkamfpjcmgafpo?hl=en)

Comment: nice extension! use this extension the code runs! but with out set F12 and click on Cisar  the code doesn´t work... why=?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your webpart properties, instead of refering the JS file with absolute URl refer like this

```
~sitecollection/SiteAssets/XTR/JSTest.js
```

Instead of Site Collection URL, specify `~sitecollection`

Comment: I try: ~/SiteAssets/XTR/JSTest.js, ~SiteAssets/XTR/JSTest.js , /Sites/Portal/SiteAssets/XTR/JSTest.js, ... allways the same . Is because the SiteAssets library?

Comment: try something like above now, if it doesnt works still give me you JS file complete URL and your site collection URL

Comment: is intranet... i did all tries..

Comment: where is your js file? site collection level or subsite level?

Comment: site leve colletion,  http://localhost/Sites/Portal/SiteAssets/XTR/JSTest.js and the page is in the same site colletion

Comment: It works with ~sitecollection.... very strange approach from Microsoft

Comment: Can you mark it as answer so that it might help other users too